# Error "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before" at struct constructor

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, struct

I am trying to write some code to optimize some Open GL functions for a program I'm writing, unfortunately, I am not exactly a C or C++ veteran, but that's partially why I'm doing this project!

So I'm creating a struct to handle 3x3 matrices and I am defining the struct as follows:

```
#ifndef MATRIX3BY3_H
#define MATRIX3BY3_H
struct Matrix3by3
{
    float ix, jx, kx;
    float iy, jy, ky;
    float iz, jz, kz;

    Matrix3by3() {}

    Matrix3by3(const Matrix3by3 &matrix)
    {
        ix = matrix.ix;
        jx = matrix.jx;
        kx = matrix.kx;

        iy = matrix.iy;
        jy = matrix.jy;
        ky = matrix.ky;

        iz = matrix.iz;
        jz = matrix.jz;
        kz = matrix.kz;
    }

    Matrix3by3 (const float _ix, const float _jx, const float _kx,
                const float _iy, const float _jy, const float _ky,
                const float _iz, const float _jz, const float _kz) :
        ix(_ix), jx(_jx), kx(_kx),
        iy(_iy), jy(_jy), ky(_ky),
        iy(_iz), jx(_jz), kz(_kz) {}
    }; 
#endif
```

And I get the error (twice)

> Expected specifier-qualifier-list
>   before 'Matrix3by3'

On the line of the first constructor. I have tried to look around for answers for this, and it seems that it has to do with the compiler not knowing that this is a type. So I have tried the following, I'll remove the innards for brevity:

```
typedef struct Matrix3by3 { ... };
```

---

```
struct Matrix3by3 { struct Matrix3by3() {} ... };
```

---

```
struct Matrix3by3 { ... } Matrix3by3;
```

---

```
typdef struct Matrix3by3;
struct Matrix3by3 { ... };
```

Which are all solutions that were suggested on blogs and articles that I saw for this error. I also saw that it may arise because of a circular dependency, but this file has no includes that include anything else, and I've even removed them just to be certain from time to time - no change.

I could write this in a objective-c class, I'm sure, but it will probably take a tiny bit more memory and cycles, and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The only thing I can think of left is some compiler/project setting that I have set by default that precludes my using this type of structure. Entirely possible, as I'm learning the language/environment.

Can any one provide some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C does not support constructors or member functions of structs.  There is no way you will get this to compile as C or Objective-C.  You need to compile this as C++ or Objective-C++, at which point it will almost compile: you have an error in your 3rd constructor, in that you're attempting to initialize the members `iy` and `jx` multiple times.  Once you fix those typos, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Ah yes, I see those errors. Had been up for a while when I hashed this out. The thing is, I've seen this type of thing in multiple other places when looking at examples of iPhone development. So I'm not certain why it works there (and even in directly downloaded examples) but not for me. I assume it's some compiler/project setting in xcode, but I'm not sure what. Or I'm missing the struct equivalent of the semicolon error

Comment: Ah! I took a second look and saw where I was setting the project to compile as the filename default, not to any specific language. Change it to Objective-C++ and it compiled just fine. In your opinion, should I make an extra effort to remain in the C-space and just do this differently, or is Objective-C++ just fine?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct { ... } Matrix3by3;
```

should work. It declares the anonymous struct as a type.

And use class instead of struct :)

Comment: I get the same error in this case, it's one that I tried, earlier, I believe as well. I *think* it's because by the time the C/C++ compiler gets to the "Matrix3by3() {}" constructor it doesn't know Matrix3by3 is a type? Still, I've seen this in other example code and I'm confused as to why it works in one and not when I've tried to emulate the structure, as I've said I'm new to direct C, coming from a different background. Have you any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What language/compiler are you translating your program with? I'd guess that you are trying to compile the code as C, while the language features you are trying to use are strictly C++-specific.

Comment: Possible. I'm using whatever the default settings of Xcode are. What's strange is an example that uses a struct in the same manner my original attempt compiles just fine. I don't see any project settings that pop out at me.

Comment: When I say "whatever the default settings of Xcode are" what I mean is this project is in objective-c, which as I understand it understands all c constructs just fine. If I wanted to do something similar to this in c, what would I use? just a class?

Comment: @Kevek: Class? There are no "classes" in C. In C you'd use a plain struct with a standalone functions for initialization and other operators.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Matrix3by3'" is a GCC-ism and it means that the token "Matrix3by3" is unknown. This is typically the case when you have a type that the compiler doesn't recognize, either because you mistyped it or because you forgot a header. In your case, it's because the type "Matrix3by3" really doesn't exist. You have two options:

1. Stop using `Matrix3by3` directly and start using `struct Matrix3by3` instead, as that's the actual type you defined.
2. Give your struct a typedef. It will look something like

   ```
   typedef struct {
       // fields here
   } Matrix3by3
   ```

Comment: If I put "struct Matrix3by3() {}" as the constructor line (and in front of the other two, as well) I get the error "Expected identifier or '(' before ')' token" looks like it understands this even less. I get the feeling that either I've set this to Objective-C without C++ which is needed, or I'm just doing something plain syntactically wrong.

Comment: From looking at other answers, and from re-reading your question, it appears that the underlying problem here is you're writing C++ and trying to run it as C.